# Using OAuth2 to access readonly Gmail feed

Tags: gmail, google-oauth

I am using OAuth 2.0 to access Gmail with scope `https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom`. Do you know if it is possible to request access (scope) in such a way that the authorization pop-up indicates that we need **read only** access.

Right now the pop says "View and manage your mail" - View and manage your mail in Gmail. This "manage" part is discouraging to many users while all we need is to view them.

Thanks, Konstantin.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no documented OAuth2 scope for read-only Gmail access right now. You can submit a feature request to the [GMail product forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/gmail) ;-)

There is also a dedicated [Suggest a feature for GMail](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=suggestions.cs) page.

Comment: Thank you, added [feature request](http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/gmail/ygZFHw-cPg0/discussion)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the readonly one: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly`